# How do I query a string in Arcobjects that has a single quote in it?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I'm trying to query values using a cursor and loop for the process of removing diacritics. The problem I am running in to is that when I try to create a `WhereClause` like so...

```
qf.WhereClause = "\""+fieldname+"\" = "+"'"+address+"'";
```

I get a COMException about my query if the value of address has a single quote in it (i.e. `Land o'Lakes`). I have tried escaping the ' with `address.Replace("'","\'")` but the resulting string is unchanged. When I attempted to double-escape with `address.Replace("'","\\'")` , the string ends up with *both* backslashes.

What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it might matter what type of data source you are hitting but in general I suspect that doubling the single quote marks is the solution.  So address.Replace( "'", "''"); should work.

Comment: That seems to have worked, but I have no idea why it does.

Comment: Because in SQL, a single quote is the escape character for a single quote.

Comment: That's hilariously evil.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use ASCII Character Codes by using the Char() function.  The ASCII code for single quote is 39 and the code for double quote is 34.  Using Char(39) will return '.

So you could say:

```
qf.WhereClause = "\""+fieldname+"\" = "+Char(39)+address+Char(39);
```

Here is a link to a list of ASCII codes: http://yorktown.cbe.wwu.edu/sandvig/shared/ASCIICodes.aspx