# How to include a single quote / apostrophe in an ArcGIS Server REST API query string

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, query-task

This is similar to [How do I query a string in Arcobjects that has a single quote in it?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20077/how-do-i-query-a-string-in-arcobjects-that-has-a-single-quote-in-it) but in my case the apostrophe is actually in the word I'm searching for: `&where=locality = 'O'CONNELL'`

This fails in an ArcGIS Server query:

[image]

Comment: This is also similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912095/how-to-insert-a-value-that-contains-an-apostrophe-single-quote

Comment: @Vince ha, I thought it was an ArcGIS glitch, but it turns out to be generic SQL

Comment: It was generic to many 4GL languages that I've used. SQL is one of a few that survived that generation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with the ArcObjects question above, the answer is to include a second single quote:

`&where=locality = 'O''CONNELL'`

[image]

Comment: I wasted ages trying other useless approaches, so I'm adding this to Stack Exchange in case it helps someone